# QGIS Elevation profile using Point Cloud and Polygon layer with Z value

Tags: qgis, polygon, elevation, point-cloud

I'm trying to use the Elevation profile tool with a point cloud and a polygon layer (with Z values). I wish to use the "capture curve" to view a section and I expected to see the polygon sits on the point cloud in the right height. I also changed the elevation Property of the polygon layer to "Absolute".

[image: Elevation profile]

However, I am getting a strange results. The polygon does not sit on the point cloud and presents random heights.

[image: Elevation view]

I made sure that the vertices heights and point cloud fit. here is a section view of the point cloud.

[image: Point Cloud vertical section]

and here is the height values of the polygon which i'm sectioning.
[image: Polygon Z values]

I've made some tests, and when all vertices heights are the same, everything works. However, if the values are not the same (as in my pic) it does not work.

Anyone has a solution?